# Mutable string color change alters character to be displayed as square

Tags: ios, swift3

I am changing the color of the last character of a table view section title and am getting an odd result for iOS 9+, swift 3.

The last character is the checkmark ✔︎ and the color is green.  The result is a green square instead of a green checkmark.  If I print to console the checkmark shows correctly.  If I remove the color change, it shows the checkmark just fine (in black).  If I use another symbol such as the double exclamation point, `‼` it works just fine.

Simplified Code

```
struct PersonConstants{
    static let DEFAULT_STATUS_INDEX : Int = 1
    static let validStatus : NSArray = ["✔︎","?","‼"]
}

let colorsArray = [
    UIColor(red: 29/255.0, green:166/255.0, blue:47/255.0, alpha:1.0),
    UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 0/255.0, blue: 255/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
    UIColor(red: 225/255.0, green: 0/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
]
```

---

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?{
    var title = String(Safe.count) + " "
    title += NSLocalizedString("Accounted", comment: "")
    title += ": " + String(PersonConstants.validStatus[0] as! NSString)
    return title
}
```

---

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    if let view = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
        view.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.black
        view.textLabel!.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 17.0)

        myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: view.textLabel!.text! as String)

        if sectionTwo.count > 0{
            myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: colorsArray[0], range: NSRange(location: (view.textLabel!.text!).characters.count-1,length:1))
            view.textLabel!.attributedText = myMutableString
            //print(myMutableString.string)
        }else{
            view.textLabel!.text = ""
        }
    }
}
```

Bad result

[image]

Comment: `String(PersonConstants.validStatus[0] as! NSString)` "Take a `String`, make it a `NSString`, then use that to make a `String`. Wut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because `NSMutableAttributedString` works with UTF-16 based offset and count, you need to pass UTF-16 based `NSRange` for the attributes of `NSMutableAttributedString`.

It's not a simple task to do in Swift 3...

```
let text = view.textLabel!.text ?? ""
let lastCharIndex = text.index(before: text.endIndex)
let lastCharUTF16Index = lastCharIndex.samePosition(in: text.utf16)
let location = text.utf16.startIndex.distance(to: lastCharUTF16Index)
let length = lastCharUTF16Index.distance(to: text.utf16.endIndex)
myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: colorsArray[0],
                             range: NSRange(location: location, length: length))
```

---

By the way, if you declare your `validStatus` as:

```
static let validStatus: [String] = ["✔︎","?","‼"]
```

You can make other parts of your code simpler:

```
title += ": " + PersonConstants.validStatus[0]
```

Comment: Thank you! You're explanation and example helped a lot.  I also appreciate your recommendation to simplify the array call as well.  Cheers